# Converting spotify json file to html

Tags: php, html, json, spotify

I am trying to convert a spotify json file to a html table. However this json file is a bit complex. I am making a mistake somewhere, but can't find out what I am doing wrong. What is the proper code?

```
<?php
    $spotifylist = "http://spotifycharts.com/api/?type=regional&country=nl&recurrence=daily&date=latest&limit=200";
    $contents = file_get_contents($spotifylist); 
    $decoded = json_decode($contents,true); 
    $results = $decoded->entries[0]->items;

    echo "<table class='chart'> <thead><tr class='row2'><th class='dw'></th><th class='song'>Artiest</th><th class='song'>Titel</th></tr></thead><tbody>";      

    foreach($results as $entry){
      $artist = $entry->track->artists->name;
      $name = $entry->track->name;
      $x = $entry + 1;  
      $color = ($x%2 == 0)? 'row2': 'row1'; 
      echo "<tr class='$color'>";   
        echo "<td class='dw'>". $x ."</td>"; 
        echo "<td class='song'>". $artist ."</td>";
        echo "<td class='song'>". $name ."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";  
    }
    echo "</tbody></table>";
?>
```

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit confused. I've cleaned it up *a little bit* in order that it can work, but I think you need to look at it more closely – it pulls very precise pieces of data out of the feed, which might not be safe.

Working code below:

```
<?php
    $spotifylist = "http://spotifycharts.com/api/?type=regional&country=nl&recurrence=daily&date=latest&limit=200";
    $contents = file_get_contents($spotifylist); 
    $decoded = json_decode($contents); 
    $results = $decoded->entries->items;

    echo "<table class='chart'> <thead><tr class='row2'><th class='dw'></th><th class='song'>Artiest</th><th class='song'>Titel</th></tr></thead><tbody>";      

    $counter = 0;

    foreach($results as $entry){
        ++$counter;

        $artist = (string)$entry->track->artists[0]->name;
        $name = $entry->track->album->name;
        $color = ($counter % 2 == 0) ? 'row2': 'row1'; 
        echo "<tr class='$color'>";   
        echo "<td class='dw'>$counter</td>"; 
        echo "<td class='song'>". $artist ."</td>";
        echo "<td class='song'>". $name ."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";  
    }

    echo "</tbody></table>";
?>
```

Comment: Have you tested this? Besides the thead, no table data is outputted in my browser.

Comment: Of course I tested it. And to make sure I tested it again just now, and got the same output as before: http://i.imgur.com/6Ekwsfq.jpg

Comment: It works in phpfiddle, thus the code is the right one. Then I have to find out why it doesn't work on my website.

Comment: I'm glad it works! Please mark the answer as correct so others can benefit too. If you have server configuration problems, perhaps post a new question on SuperUser?

Comment: I accept your answer if I have the code fully working also on my website. One other thing, I wasn't clear. However I meant the name to be the title of the single, not the album.

Comment: You can pull out the track name using `$name = $entry->track->name;` rather than `$name = $entry->track->album->name;`  I can't help you with server configuration, and your question was not about server configuration. You may wish to post a new question so that others can investigate your server problems.

Comment: I don't have server problems. Previously I also had a table of decoded json on my site. Thus that can't be it.

Comment: The code works great for me. The code works on PHPFiddle. Does your server support fetching from remote URLs? Is there something between your server and that URL? Have you tried echoing `$contents` to see what you're actually being sent? This really is a whole new question.

Comment: You are right. This is the echo of contents: 
Found
The document has moved here.

Apache/2.4 Server at spotifycharts.com Port 80 (where "Here" is the json url)